# Rails: How do I resolve: Pundit::NotDefinedError in PostsController#show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

whenever I run the below program and try to view my posts (in my show view) as any user, I am introduced to this error page:

```
Pundit::NotDefinedError in PostsController#show
unable to find policy of nil
```

Within that error page:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @posts                 # <- The error highlights this line
  end
```

I'm not sure how to get around this dilemma as I'm just learning about Pundit Policy rules and am new to Rails and Ruby. Any help would be much appreciated. Below are my policy pages and related pages:

User.rb Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :posts

  def admin?
    role == 'admin'
  end

  def moderator?
    role == 'moderator'
  end

  def member?
    role == 'member'
  end

  def guest?
    role == 'guest'
  end
end
```

Application Controller

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
      # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
      include Pundit
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
      before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

      rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError do |exception|
        redirect_to root_url, alert: exception.message
      end

      protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
      end
    end
```

Posts Controller

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
    #  before_action :flash_attack

    #  protected


    #  def flash_attack
    #    flash[:notice] = "Create/Edit/Comment on a post!"
    #  end

      def index
        @posts = Post.all
        authorize @posts
      end

      def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        authorize @posts
      end

      def new
        @post = Post.new
        authorize @post
      end

      def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body))
        authorize @post
        if @post.save
          flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
          redirect_to @post
        else
          flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
          render :new
        end
      end

      def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        authorize @post
      end

      def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        authorize @post
        if @post.update_attributes(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body))
          flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
          redirect_to @post
        else
          flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
          render :edit
        end
      end
    end
```

Application Policy

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    user.present?
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    user.present? && (record.user == user || user.admin?)

  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    update?
  end

  def scope
    record.class
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

Posts Policy

```
    class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
      class Scope < Scope
        def resolve
          if user.admin?
            scope.all
          else
            scope.where(:published => true)
          end
        end

      def index?
        true
      end

      def show?
        true
      end
      def update?
        user.admin? or not post.published?
      end
    end
    end
```

Index View

```
    <h1>All Posts</h1>

    <% if policy(Post.new).create? %>
    <%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>

    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <div class="media">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">
              <%= link_to post.title, post %>
            </h4>
            <small>
              submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= post.user.name unless post.user.nil? %><br>
              <%= post.comments.count %> Comments
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Show View

```
<h1> <%= @post.title %> </h1>

<% if policy(@post).edit? %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>

<p> <%= @post.body %> </p>
```

Thanks in advance everyone. Let me know if any more information would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@posts` is `nil` in show action, you should use `@post` as such:

```
authorize @post
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working on a **Rails 6** API only application with the **Pundit** gem.

I was running into the error below when I test my Pundit authorization for my controller actions:

> Pundit::NotDefinedError - unable to find policy of nil

**Here's how I solved**:

The instance variables called by the `authorize` method in your controller must correspond to the instance variable of the controller action being called.

So for the `index` action it should be `@posts`:

```
authorize @posts
```

For the `show` action it should be `@post`:

```
authorize @post
```

and for the `create` action it should be `@post`

```
authorize @post
```

and so on.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**